# Enable the user to upload background Image

Tags: best-practice, css, frontend

How do you enable a user to upload a css background Image?

Do you write some inline css in the page header with twig markup?
Do you write some twig markup inside a css file?

Or do you fake a background image by add an image and then position it absolute?

What's the best practice there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply add it inline to your `body` tag like so:

```
<body style="background-image: url({{ myGlobal.myAssetsField.first().url }})">
```

If you want to only use it with selected templates, you'd better use Craft's [`includeCss`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/includecss) tag:

```
{% set bodyCss %}
    .myBodyClass {
        background-image: url({{ myGlobal.myAssetsField.first().url }});
    }
{% endset %}

{% includeCss bodyCss %}
```